# Editing URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am trying edit the middle of a URL in order to filter search results on a page. For example, the URL could be:

```
http://belklucy.idxbroker.com/idx/results/listings?pt=all&ccz=zipcode&zipcode[]=29492&widgetReferer=true
```

and I would need to change the "pt=all" to "pt=lse" using jQuery. Is my best option using split() ? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this is not what jquery is for.

Comment: well... i mean, jquery does have this... `$.param` method that makes generating the queryparam string easier. Maintain the values in an object, then when you need it to be a url param it out.

Comment: Normally you would show *what you have tried*, rather than asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: Additionally, this is very unclear.  Does the URL *always* have `pt=all`? Or do you need to be able to address different parameters, which may have different values?

Comment: thanks @cale_b I'll do that next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't do magic. If the string is fixed, you could use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var url = 'http://belklucy.idxbroker.com/idx/results/listings?pt=all&ccz=zipcode&zipcode[]=29492&widgetReferer=true';
url = url.replace('pt=all', 'pt=lse');
  console.log(url);
```